# If $\frac{1+u^2}{\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}}$ and $\frac{1+v^2}{\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}}$ are constant then so are $u$ and $v$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Take $u(x,y),v(x,y)$ functions from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to itself. Given that the following functions are all constant, can we conclude that $u$ and $v$ are also constant?

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1+u^2}{\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}}\:,\:g(x,y) = \frac{uv}{\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}}\:,\:h(x,y) = \frac{1+v^2}{\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}}$$

This seems like it would be somewhat obvious but I cannot seem to prove it. I tried taking derivatives to show that $u_x=u_y=v_x=v_y=0$ but this turned out to be harder than I thought. I also tried taking something like $a = 1+u^2$, $b = 1+v^2$ so that $f$ and $g$ become $f = a/\sqrt{a+b-1}$, $g = b/\sqrt{a+b-1}$ and tried to solve for $a$ and $b$ but it seemed to lead nowhere.

Comment: Typo in the title.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thank you. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a system of two equations in two unknowns which can be written

$$\begin{cases}f^2(a+b-1)=a^2,\\fb=ga\end{cases}$$ together with the conditions $a,b\ge0$, $a+b\ge1$.

The first equation describes a parabola of vertical axis, while the second is a half-line. They intersect at one or two points. Solve the quadratic equation

$$a^2-f(f+g)a+f^2=0$$ for $a$.

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase your question, you have a map ${\mathbb R}^2 \to {\mathbb R}^3$

$$
\Phi(u,v)=\bigg(\frac{1+u^2}{\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}}\:,\: \frac{uv}{\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}}\:,\: \frac{1+v^2}{\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}}\bigg)
$$

and the question is whether $\Phi$ is injective. Answer : no, since $\Phi(-u,-v)=\Phi(u,v)$.